# Module 'pyautogui' has no 'typewrite' member

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to use PyAutoGUI to write for me, but none of the pyautogui stuff works.

Here is an example of my code:

```
import pyautogui, time

time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.typewrite("Test")
```

Here is the error message i get:

`AttributeError: module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'typewrite'`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you done a `pip install pyautogui` from the command line?

Comment: Yes. I have @rajah9

Answer (score 1):

Check if folder or script's name is **pyautogui** if it is then change it to any other name

```
import pyautogui, time

time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.typewrite("Test")
```